# Evitar crear un archivo jrxml(iReport) para cada uno de los reportes xml, para generarlos en pdf con JasperReports y java

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

Como dice la pregunta, quiero evitar crear un archivo JRXML(hecho con iReport) para cada uno de mis reportes que ya están hechos en XML, o por lo menos solo crear uno genérico.

Si alguien ya lo ha hecho, me imagino que a muchos les ha pasado que tienen que hacer un JRXML para cada uno de sus reportes , pero en este caso tengo miles de reportes que necesito que se generen en pdf.

Entonces mi pregunta, ¿ es posible hacer un clase o solo un archivo JRXML(generico), para poder exportar mis reportes a pdf ?

Nota: mis reportes cambian totalmente, no se parecen en nada, siempre obviamente tienen la query y los campos a mostrar, pero esas dos cambian totalmente en los reportes.

Tecnologias utilizadas: iReport, JasperReports , Java, Eclipse, Maven

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si tus reportes no tienen más formato que el de una tabla simple (filas y columnas) podrías enviarle un `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` al reporte. Con esto lo que harías es que en tu código crearías un `List` con los datos que deseas mostrar. Claro, esto siempre te limita a tener siempre la misma cantidad de columnas a mostrar, y los nombres de columnas podrías mandarlos por parámetros para que sean variables.

Más o menos el ejemplo para crearlo sería así:

Clase genérica que contendrá los datos (es solo un ejemplo)

```
public class RepoCompra implements Serializable{  
    private String idMercancia;
    private String descriMercancia;
    private String idArticulo;
    private String descriArticulo;
    private String descriUnidadMedida;
    private String descriMarca;
    private String nombreProveedor;
    private String numFactura;
    private String descriBodega;
    private Integer cantidad;
    private BigDecimal precio;
    private Date fecCompra;
    private Date fecRecepcion;

    public RepoCompra() {
    }

    public RepoCompra(String idMercancia, String descriMercancia,String idArticulo, String descriArticulo, String descriUm, String descriMarca, String nombreProveedor, String numFactura, String descriBodega, Integer cantidad, BigDecimal precio, Date fecCompra, Date fecRecepcion) {
        this.idMercancia=idMercancia;
        this.descriMercancia=descriMercancia;
        this.idArticulo=idArticulo;
        this.descriArticulo=descriArticulo;
        this.descriUnidadMedida = descriUm;
        this.descriMarca = descriMarca;
        this.nombreProveedor = nombreProveedor;
        this.numFactura = numFactura;
        this.descriBodega = descriBodega;
        this.cantidad = cantidad;
        this.precio = precio;
        this.fecCompra = fecCompra;
        this.fecRecepcion = fecRecepcion;
    }
}
```

Los nombres de los atributos que coloques en esta clase deberán coincidir con los nombres de los `campos` (`Fields`) que coloques en el archivo `JRXML`.

Deberás crear una `List` de esta clase:

```
List<RepoCompra> lstCompra;
```

Y deberás inicializarla con los datos que necesitas.

Creas el `Map` con los parámetros que le enviarás:

```
Map<String, Object> parametros = new HashMap<>();
parametros.put("par1", par1);
...
```

Creas el `JRBeanCollectionDataSource` y el `JasperPrint`:

```
JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanCollectionDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstCompra);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(rutaJasper, parametros, beanCollectionDataSource);
```

Y lo exportas (en este ejemplo a PDF):

```
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();
ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, servletOutputStream);
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
```

Mi ejemplo de una aplicación web.
Espero te pueda servir mi solución.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias, he utilizado los metodos Stream y HashMap, con ello pude obtener la data, y sin utilizar jrxml pude consumir los datos del archivo xml y luego utilicé Itext, asi pude generar el reporte para cualquier matrix de datos. Gracias